# How to extend Expiration Date on Key file | Access Management 9.6

Tags: sites-9.6, access-management

We have Installed Access management for Tridion Sites 9.6. using this [link](https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2020/12/03/installation-of-access-management-in-sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/). Initially, we created Custom certificate Using Powershell script Mentioned in link and later we updated our own Certificate on appsettings.json.

Observed key file found under **Access management\bin\Key** Folder and having Activation Date & Expiration Date on that file, But having different expiration Date(2022-12-31) on My own Certificate. how to extend this Expiration Date on key file? will update automatically or if we give any Date (ex:2025-01-01) it will work? Can you please suggest how to proceed.

```
<activationDate>2022-01-18T06:26:16.4511521Z</activationDate>
<expirationDate>2022-04-18T06:26:16.4511521Z</expirationDate>
```

Comment: Did you follow the recommended key rollover process? - https://docs.rws.com/956379/785868/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/changing-the-signing-certificate-with-key-rollover

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to generate a self-signed certificate that expired three years from now you could add the NotAfter switch, for example:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -dnsname $env:COMPUTERNAME -NotAfter [System.DateTime]::AddYears(3)
```

Alternatively, you could pass a specific date with the NoteAfter switch, for example:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -dnsname $env:COMPUTERNAME -NotAfter "2024-01-01"
```

Comment: Now I'm using my own certificate not self-signed certificate. Then this key file is not valid for my own certificate or need to re-generate Self signed certificate?